# Printing a String at a specific Coordinate in c#

Tags: c#, string, position

I have a little thing here where I must create a program that prints out a string at a specific coordinate. So, I know that I need 2 variables for the string position and a string variable for the string, but then I have no idea on how to continue. Any ideas?

EDIT
this is how far ive come:

```
class ColoredText
{
    public int x, y; // koordinaterna
    public string hello;
    ConsoleColor färg;

    public ColoredText(int x, int y, string Position)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?  Any code?

Comment: That is going to depend entirely on what you mean by "prints out a string at a specific coordinate". On a webpage? On the console? On a Windows form? On a newspaper>

Comment: I believe that you are looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76c5db29.aspx

```
public void DrawStringPointF(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Create string to draw.
    String drawString = "Sample Text";

    // Create font and brush.
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
    SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    // Create point for upper-left corner of drawing.
    PointF drawPoint = new PointF(150.0F, 150.0F);

    // Draw string to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(drawString, drawFont, drawBrush, drawPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're talking about printing a string at a specific coordinate on a FORM then you can do as follows...

Create a new label and place it on your form then do something like...

Now you can set the labels coordinates by doing the following..

```
        int xCoordinate = 0;
        int yCoordinate = 0;
        string labelText = "Enter your text here";

        label1.Location = new Point(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        label1.Text = labelText;
```

Answer (score 0):

based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx)

```
class ColoredText
{
  public int x, y; // koordinaterna
  public string hello;
  ConsoleColor farg;  // removed the utf-8 char

    public ColoredText(int x, int y, string Position)
    {
       Console.ForegroundColor = farg;
       Console.SetCursorPostion(x,y);
       Console.Write(Position);
       Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tagged C#. So i'll go with what I know. In WPF, you may want to use a Canvas or Grid.
With Grid you want to set the margin of children elements.
With Canvas you want to set the Top and Left properties.

```
// In XAML
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="TB"/>
</Grid>

// In code-behind:
Point p = new Point(x, y);
TB.Margin = new Thickness(p.x, p.y, 0, 0);
TB.Text = "Lorem ipsum";
```